# PyAudio - crash when terminating

Tags: python, multithreading, anaconda, pyaudio

I'm using pyaudio for my audio playback and i'm having trouble stopping it on command.
When i let my playlist play from start to finish it works perfectly but if i try to interrupt the playback beforehand it does stop but it also crashes python and the error report says the fault module is _portaudio.pyd.
i'm using anaconda 2.4.1 with python 2.7.11 64 bit.
these are the functions that control playback:

```
    def play_stop(self):
        self.is_playing=self.toggle_flag(self.is_playing)
        t=Create_thread(self.snd_play)
        t.start()

    def snd_play(self):
        global stream
        global p
        self.plist=list()
        p=pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self.ind=self.buffersize-1
        self.currind=1
        for i,f in enumerate(self.file_list[:self.buffersize]):
            self.plist.append(wave.open(f,"rb"))
        while len(self.plist)>0 and self.is_playing:

            if len(self.plist)<self.buffersize:

                self.ind+=1
                try:
                    self.plist.append(wave.open(self.file_list[self.ind],"rb"))
                except IndexError:
                    pass
        self.indexcounter.setText("Zvuk: %d/%d" %(self.currind,len(self.file_list)))
        stream=p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(self.plist[0].getsampwidth()),
                      channels=self.plist[0].getnchannels(),
                                rate=self.plist[0].getframerate(),
                                output=True)
            data=self.plist[0].readframes(self.plist[0].getnframes())
            stream.write(data)
            stream.stop_stream()
            #stream.close()
            self.plist.pop(0)
            self.currind+=1

            try:
                sleep(abs(float(self.playList.item(self.currind-1,1).text())))
            except TypeError:
                QtGui.QMessageBox.critical(self,u"Greška", "Interval nije cijeli ni decimalni broj")
                break
            except:
                    pass

        else:
            self.is_playing=False
            stream.stop_stream()
            stream.close()
            p.terminate()
```

python itself doesn't throw any errors before the crash and it crashes only if i try to stop the stream, close it and terminate the pyaudio instance before it's done playing. i installed pyaudio with pip
and as you can see the snd_play() method is always executed in a new thread which is why i toggle the playing flag before instantiating as i assume all the threads will stop anyway when their functions are done